# Firebase Authentication database interaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to access the "Authentication" database in Firebase?

I'm building an app which uses the Firebase anonymous authentication
I would like to access the Firebase "Authentication" database to check the last login of the user.
Tried looking through the web but didn't find any reference.

Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Thanks Frank! I'll reference to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for you to access the timestamp of when a specific user last logged in. Most developers end up storing this type of information in their Firebase Database, for example with the structure outlined in the section [structuring your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-structuring-db).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase launched the admin node.js sdk. You can look users by uid or email and get their metadata like creation date and last login date.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users